# jquery ui datepicker onSelect method syntax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, razor

Hey everyone I am having problems with the syntax with a jquery ui datepicker onSelect event. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datePicker').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var serviceID = $('#Service').val();
            var providerID = $('#Provider').val();
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Calendar/FreeSlots")', { serviceId: serviceID, providerId: providerID, date: dateText  }, function (slots) {
                var TimeSlots = $('#TimeSlots');
                TimeSlots.empty();
                $.each(slots, function (index, slot) {
                    TimeSlots.append($('<option/>', {
                         value: slot.value,
                         text: slot.text
                    }));//end append
                }); //end each
            }    //end onSelect
    }); //End datepicker attributes ---->  Firebug Error: missing ) after argument list 
}); ///End Document Ready
```

I have checked and double checked but I cannot find out how to fix the syntax. You can see in the comments where Firebug is telling me about the syntax error. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't close your `$.getJSON` call

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("Calendar/FreeSlots")', { serviceId: serviceID, providerId: providerID, date: dateText  }, function (slots) {
            var TimeSlots = $('#TimeSlots');
            TimeSlots.empty();
            $.each(slots, function (index, slot) {
                TimeSlots.append($('<option/>', {
                     value: slot.value,
                     text: slot.text
                }));
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

on end on Select you forgot to close $.getJson

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("Calendar/FreeSlots")', { serviceId: serviceID, providerId: providerID, date: dateText  }, function (slots) {
           var TimeSlots = $('#TimeSlots');
            TimeSlots.empty();
            $.each(slots, function (index, slot) {
                TimeSlots.append($('<option/>', {
                     value: slot.value,
                     text: slot.text
                }));//end append
            }); //end each
        }); //end onSelect
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `} // endOnSelect` does not end your onSelect, but your `getJSON`.

Before that `}`, add another

```
}); // end getJSON
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the closing `}` on your `$.each()` call:

```
}));//end append
```

should be:

```
    }) //end append
}); //end each
```

Answer (score 0):

People fixed your problem. But why aren't you using a JS debugger? Firebug for firefox, Chrome and a few others has it built-in, IE has Developer Tools. They come in handy you know.

Comment: He did say: `You can see in the comments where Firebug is telling me about the syntax error.`

Comment: Bah. Didn't read the end TLDR; .. need to get my coffee.

Comment: I am using Firebug but i am very new to JS.